# how to open specific div by class name onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have many `div` with the class name `dis`

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dis">Content</div>
<div class="dis">Content</div>
<div class="dis">Content</div> and so on ...
```

And have many **images**:

```
<img src="icons/image1.png" class="admoicn" onclick="toggle_visibility('dis');" >
<img src="icons/image2.png" class="admoicn" onclick="toggle_visibility('dis');" >
<img src="icons/image3.png" class="admoicn" onclick="toggle_visibility('dis');" >
```

**CSS:**

```
.dis{  
    display:none;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;  
}
```

**javascript:**

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementsByClassName(id)[0];
    if(e.style.display =="block"){
        e.style.display ="none";
    }
    else{
        e.style.display ="block";
    }
}
```

Onclicking any image the specific div `dis` should be open, I mean onclicking third `image3.png` the third number of div `dis` should be open and close all opened `dis` div.

I think it's the `array` problem on `javascript` class and I don't know how to fix it. I'm very new to `javascript`.

Comment: Don't know how to do it in your situation without having a more complete look at your markup. You can do it by index if all the `dis` elements have no other siblings, and same for the images. But we shouldn't be guessing at details like this.

Comment: Are the index of images and divs same, for example. If I click the first image should u show the first div and so on, do they follow that order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an argument to the `toggle_visibility` function:

```
<img src="icons/image1.png" class="admoicn" onclick="toggle_visibility('dis', 0);" >
<img src="icons/image2.png" class="admoicn" onclick="toggle_visibility('dis', 1);" >
<img src="icons/image3.png" class="admoicn" onclick="toggle_visibility('dis', 2);" >
```

And use it as index to the array:

```
function toggle_visibility(id, index) {                    // added index here
    // close all divs
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        els[i].style.display ="none"
    }

    // show selected div
    els[index].style.display = "block";
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo here.**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/zbL84pc2/)

By the way, if the argument is a class name, you should really name it that (not `id` as you are now, it is very misleading).

Comment: this does not close all the opened divs

Comment: Can't you pass `this` into the onclick handler and not have to use indexes?

Comment: @BobRodes yes, you could. I don't pass it now because it is not really needed (I just manipulate the divs, not the images), but you could if you needed.

Comment: Passing `this` would eliminate the need to pass individual indices since the index can then be determined dynamically. However, it makes assumptions about the markup that the OP would need to clarify.

Comment: Ok, both of those make sense.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, this [codepen](http://codepen.io/rohitbind/pen/zBjWJY) will help you to achieve it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").click(function(){
        var classname = this.id;
        $('div').removeClass('show');
        $("."+classname).addClass('show');
    });
});
```

```css
img{
      cursor:pointer;
      width : 30px;
      padding:20px;
      border:1px solid #333;
}

div{
      display:none;
}
.show{
      display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149384.svg" id="Phone" />
<img src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149181.svg" id="chem" />
<img src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149098.svg" id="cam" />

<div class="Phone">
    <h1>Hi This is phone</h1>
</div>
<div class="chem">
    <h1>Hi This is chem reaction</h1>
</div>
<div class="cam">
    <h1>Hi This is camera</h1>
</div>
```